# Overloading operator on a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, either

Here is a definition of a `Result` class that aims to simulate the logic of the Either monad from Haskell (`Left` is `Failure`; `Right` is `Success`).

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename S, typename F>
class result
{
  private:
    S succ;
    F fail;
    bool pick;

  public:
    /// Chain results of two computations.
    template <typename T>
    result<T,F> operator&&(result<T,F> _res) {
      if (pick == true) {
        return _res;
      } else {
        return failure(fail);
      }
    }

    /// Chain two computations.
    template <typename T>
    result<T,F> operator>>=(std::function<result<T,F>(S)> func) {
      if (pick == true) {
        return func(succ);
      } else {
        return failure(fail);
      }
    }

    /// Create a result that represents success.
    static result success(S _succ) {
      result res;
      res.succ = _succ;
      res.pick = true;

      return res;
    }

    /// Create a result that represents failure.
    static result failure(F _fail) {
      result res;
      res.fail = _fail;
      res.pick = false;

      return res;
    }
};
```

When trying to compose two results using the `&&` operator, all is well:

```cpp
int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  // Works!
  auto res1 = result<int, std::string>::success(2);
  auto res2 = result<int, std::string>::success(3);
  auto res3 = res1 && res2;
}
```

But when attempting to chain computations on top of the result, a compilation error appears:

```cpp
result<int, std::string>
triple(int val)
{
  if (val < 100) {
    return result<int, std::string>::success(val * 3);
  } else {
    return result<int, std::string>::failure("can't go over 100!");
  }
}

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  // Does not compile!
  auto res4 = result<int, std::string>::success(2);
  auto res5a = res4 >>= triple;
  auto res5b = res4 >>= triple >>= triple;
}
```

The error from `clang++` is as follows:

```
minimal.cpp:82:21: error: no viable overloaded '>>='
  auto res5a = res4 >>= triple;
               ~~~~ ^   ~~~~~~
minimal.cpp:26:17: note: candidate template ignored: could not match
      'function<result<type-parameter-0-0, std::__1::basic_string<char,
      std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > (int)>' against
      'result<int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,
      std::__1::allocator<char> > > (*)(int)'
    result<T,F> operator>>=(std::function<result<T,F>(S)> func) {
                ^
minimal.cpp:83:32: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('result<int,
      std::string> (int)' and 'result<int, std::string> (*)(int)')
  auto res5b = res4 >>= triple >>= triple;
```

Any idea as to how to fix this issue?

Comment: From what I see, `triple` is a function. Did you try calling it, like you do with `result::success`? Voted to close as a typo.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius the idea is to supply the function as an argument to the `>>=` operator. What kind of typo is there?

Comment: On top of formerlyknownas_463035818's answer, `auto res5b = res4 >>= triple >>= triple;` will not work without additional operator for two function pointers or an explicit brackets around `res4 >>= triple`, because `operator >>=` is a right-to-left one. It will try first to apply `>>=` on `triple` and `triple`.

Comment: I wrote a detailed post explaining how to implement `Result` cleanly and efficiently so that it's a sum type. It solves your issues, and it avoids using `std::function` so that the compiler can inline everything. The syntax ends up being a lot closer to Haskell's

Answer (score 4):

This works

```
auto f = std::function< result<int, std::string>(int)>(triple);
auto res5a = res4 >>= f;
```

I cannot give a good concise explanation, only that much: Type deduction does not take into acount conversions and `triple` is a `result<int,std::string>()(int)` not a `std::function`.

You dont have to use `std::function` but you can accept any callable with something like:

```
template <typename G>
auto operator>>=(G func) -> decltype(func(std::declval<S>())) {
    if (pick == true) {
        return func(succ);
    } else {
        return failure(fail);
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3BTs1ApfpBgnzjS0)

Note that `std::function` comes with some overhead. It uses type erasure to be able to store all kinds of callables. When you want to pass only one callable there is no need to pay that cost.

For the second line @Yksisarvinen's comment already summarizes it. For the sake of completeness I simply quote it here

> `auto res5b = res4 >>= triple >>= triple;` will not work without
>   additional operator for two function pointers or an explicit brackets
>   around `res4 >>= triple`, because `operator >>=` is a right-to-left one.
>   It will try first to apply `>>=` on triple and triple.

PS: I dont know Either and your code is a bit more functional style than what I am used to, maybe you can get similar out of [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional)?

Answer (score 2):

So, in C++, a `std::function` is not the base class of anything of interest.  You cannot deduce the type of a `std::function` from a function or a lambda.

So your:

```
/// Chain two computations.
template <typename T>
result<T,F> operator>>=(std::function<result<T,F>(S)> func)
```

will only deduce when passed an actual `std::function`.

Now, what you really mean is "something that takes an S and returns a `result<T,F>` for some type `T`".

This isn't how you say it in C++.

As noted, `>>=` is right-associative.  I might propose `->*` instead, which is left-to-right.

Second, your `failure` static function won't work right, as it returns the wrong type often.

```
template<class F>
struct failure {
  F t;
};
template<class F>
failure(F)->failure{F};
```

then add a constructor taking a `failure<F>`.

```
/// Chain two computations.
template<class Self, class Rhs,
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<result, std::decay_t<Self>>{}, bool> = true
>
auto operator->*( Self&& self, Rhs&& rhs )
-> decltype( std::declval<Rhs>()( std::declval<Self>().succ ) )
{
  if (self.pick == true) {
    return std::forward<Rhs>(rhs)(std::forward<Self>(self).succ);
  } else {
    return failure{std::forward<Self>(self).fail};
  }
}
```

I am now carefully paying attention to r/lvalue ness of the types involved, and will move if possible.

```
template<class F>
struct failure {
    F f;
};
template<class F>
failure(F&&)->failure<std::decay_t<F>>;

template<class S>
struct success {
    S s;
};
template<class S>
success(S&&)->success<std::decay_t<S>>;


template <class S, class F>
class result
{
  private:
    std::variant<S, F> state;

  public:
    bool successful() const {
      return state.index() == 0;
    }

    template<class Self,
        std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<result, std::decay_t<Self>>{}, bool> = true
    >
    friend decltype(auto) s( Self&& self ) {
        return std::get<0>(std::forward<Self>(self).state);
    }
    template<class Self,
        std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<result, std::decay_t<Self>>{}, bool> = true
    >
    friend decltype(auto) f( Self&& self ) {
        return std::get<1>(std::forward<Self>(self).state);
    }

    /// Chain results of two computations.
    template<class Self, class Rhs,
        std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<result, std::decay_t<Self>>{}, bool> = true
    >
    friend std::decay_t<Rhs> operator&&(Self&& self, Rhs&& rhs) {
      if (self.successful()) {
        return success{s(std::forward<Rhs>(rhs))};
      } else {
        return failure{f(std::forward<Self>(self))};
      }
    }

    /// Chain two computations.
    template<class Self, class Rhs,
        std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<result, std::decay_t<Self>>{}, bool> = true
    >        
    friend auto operator->*(Self&&self, Rhs&& rhs)
    -> decltype( std::declval<Rhs>()( s( std::declval<Self>() ) ) )
    {
      if (self.successful()) {
        return std::forward<Rhs>(rhs)(s(std::forward<Self>(self)));
      } else {
        return failure{f(std::forward<Self>(self))};
      }
    }

    template<class T>
    result( success<T> s ):
      state(std::forward<T>(s.s))
    {}
    template<class T>
    result( failure<T> f ):
      state(std::forward<T>(f.f))
    {}
    explicit operator bool() const { return successful(); }
};
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bee6a90d56eea699).

Uses [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17).

Answer (score 1):

## Implementing `Result` cleanly and efficently

C++ can represent a `Result` type just as cleanly and efficiently as haskell. Like Haskell, C++ has true *sum types*, and we can encapsulate the entirety of their functionality with a tagged union. In addition, by taking advantage of implicit construction, we can represent `Success` and `Failure` as types instead of static member functions (this makes things a lot cleaner).

### Defining `Success` and `Failure`

These are really simple. They're just wrapper classes, so we can implement them as aggregates. In addition, using C++17's template deduction guides, we won't have to specify the template parameters for `Failure` and `Success`. Instead, we'll just be able to write `Success{10}`, or `Failure{"Bad arg"}`.

```
template <class F>
class Failure {
   public: 
    F value;
};
template<class F>
Failure(F) -> Failure<F>; 

template <class S>
class Success {
   public:
    S value;

    // This allows chaining from an initial Success
    template<class Fun>
    auto operator>>(Fun&& func) const {
        return func(value); 
    }
};
template <class S>
Success(S) -> Success<S>;
```

### Defining `Result`

`Result` is a sum type. That means it can be either a success or a failure, but not both. We can represent this with a union, which we'll tag with a `was_success` bool.

```
template < class S, class F>
class Result {
    union {
        Success<S> success; 
        Failure<F> failure; 
    };
    bool was_success = false; // We set this just to ensure it's in a well-defined state
   public:
    // Result overloads 1 through 4
    Result(Success<S> const& s) : success(s), was_success(true) {}
    Result(Failure<F> const& f) : failure(f), was_success(false) {}
    Result(Success<S>&& s) : success(std::move(s)), was_success(true) {}
    Result(Failure<F>&& f) : failure(std::move(f)), was_success(false) {}

    // Result overloads 5 through 8
    template<class S2>
    Result(Success<S2> const& s) : success{S(s.value)}, was_success(true) {}
    template<class F2>
    Result(Failure<F2> const& f) : failure{F(f.value)}, was_success(false) {}
    template<class S2>
    Result(Success<S2>&& s) : success{S(std::move(s.value))}, was_success(true) {}
    template<class F2>
    Result(Failure<F2>&& f) : failure{F(std::move(f.value))}, was_success(false) {}

    // Result overloads 9 through 10
    Result(Result const&) = default;
    Result(Result&&) = default; 

    template<class S2> 
    Result<S2, F> operator&&(Result<S2, F> const& res) {
        if(was_success) {
            return res; 
        } else {
            return Failure{failure}; 
        }
    }

    template<class Fun, class Ret = decltype(valueOf<Fun>()(success.value))>
    auto operator>>(Fun&& func) const
        -> Ret
    {
        if(was_success) {
            return func(success.value); 
        } else {
            return failure; 
        }
    }

    ~Result() {
        if(was_success) {
            success.~Success<S>(); 
        } else {
            failure.~Failure<F>(); 
        }
    }
};
```

#### Explaining `Result(...)`

A result is either constructed from a success or a failure.

- Overloads 1 through 4 just handle the basic copy and move construction from `Success` and `Failure` objects;
- Overloads 5 trhough 8 handle the case where we want to do an implicit conversion (as in the case of a string literal to a `std::string.`
- Overloads 9 and 10 handle move and copy construction of `Result`.

#### Explaining `operator>>`

This is pretty similar to your implementation of `operator>>=`, and i'll explain the reasoning behind my changes.

```
    template<class Fun, class Ret = decltype(valueOf<Fun>()(success.value))>
    auto operator>>(Fun&& func) const
        -> Ret
    {
        if(was_success) {
            return func(success.value); 
        } else {
            return failure; 
        }
    }
```

**Why not use `std::function`?** `std::function` is a type-erasing wrapper. That means that it uses virtual function calls under the hood, which slow things down. By using an unconstrained template, we make it much easier for the compiler to optimize stuff.

**Why use `>>` instead of `>>=`?** I used `>>` because `>>=` has weird behavior since it's an assignment operator. The statement `a >>= b >>= c` is actually `a >>= (b >>= c)`, which is not what we intended.

**What does `class Ret = decltype(valueOf<Fun>()(success.value))` do?** That defines a template parameter which is defaulted to the return type of the function you pass. This enables us to avoid using `std::function` while also allowing us to use lambdas.

#### Explaining `~Result()`

Because `Result` contains a union, we have to manually specify how to destruct it. (Classes containing `Result` *won't* have to do this - once we specify it inside `Result`, everything behaves like normal). This is pretty straight-forward. If it contains the `Success` object, we destroy that one. Otherwise, we destroy the `failure` one.

```
   // Result class

   ~Result() {
        if(was_success) {
            success.~Success<S>(); 
        } else {
            failure.~Failure<F>(); 
        }
    }
```

## Updating your example for my implementation

Now that we've written a `Result` class, we can update your definitions of `triple` and `main`.

### New definition of `triple`

Pretty straight-forward; we just replaced your `success` and `failure` functions with the `Success` and `Failure` types.

```
auto triple(int val) -> Result<int, std::string>
{
    if (val < 100) {
      return Success{val * 3};
    } else {
        return Failure{"can't go over 100"};
    }
}
```

### New definition of `main`

I added a `print` function so we can actually see some output. It's just a lambda. There are two computations done, one for `ans` and the other for `ans2`. The one for `ans` prints 18, because `triple` doesn't push the number over 100, but the one for `ans2` doesn't print anything because it results in a failure.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto print = [](auto value) -> Result<decltype(value), std::string> {
        std::cout << "Obtained value: " << value << '\n';
        return Success{value}; 
    };
    auto ans = Success{2} >> triple >> triple >> print;
    auto ans2 = Success{2} >> triple >> triple >> triple >> triple >> triple >> print;
}
```

#### [You can play with the code here!](https://godbolt.org/z/JnzfOR)